# diodes circuit analysis problem

Tags: diodes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH7hWh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

assuming the diodes are silicon diodes (o.7 volt) which one is on/off and why , and what is the current through or voltage cross each on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you could draw the circuit is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7JVGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 2V supply V4 basically "pushes" the other supplies up by 2V, which simplifies to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkUwRl.png)</sup>

The only diode that would be on would be D2 because the voltage at the cathode of D2 would be 7-0.7 = 6.3V, which would reverse bias the other diodes, thus turning them off. The current through the resistor is therefore 6.3/2k = 3.15mA, which is also the current through D2.